# How can I use a word, which parses its input inside a definition of another word?

Tags: forth

Suppose there is a word `string` which works like so: `64 string var$`, and the result of `var$` execution is an address of the first byte of the allocated memory and '0' to reflect the used space of the 64 bytes being allocated for a string. Now you can use it like this, `s" Hallo" var$ $!`, and this gives back the starting address of the memory and a '5' for the length of the string being stored there.

Now the problem, defining a word like so:

```
: HelloWorld 64 string HW$ s" HelloWorld!" HW$ $! ;
```

will not work, because `HW$` is evaluated of an (not defined) word.

How can I get out of this?

I tried what I have described before with ESP32Forth, and it doesn't work, which lead to my question.

Comment: Isn't this what REVEAL is for?  My Forth is rusty, so I may be off base.

Comment: Unfortunately, ESP32Forth does not have REVEAL. I tried to understand, what is written here:https://www.forth.com/starting-forth/11-forth-compiler-defining-words/ about REVEAL...but honestly...I didn't understand it fully.

Comment: Do you expect `HW$` to be visible outside of the definition for `HelloWorld`? Do you expect a separate memory range to be allocated for each invocation of `HelloWorld` (e.g., if `HelloWorld` recursively calls itself)?

Answer (score 2):

To parse the input inside a definition you have to use an immediate word (a Forth definition whose compilation semantics are to perform its execution semantics in compilation state, see [`immediate`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/IMMEDIATE)), or temporary switch to interpretation state via `[ ... ]` (see [3.4.5 Compilation](https://forth-standard.org/standard/usage#usage:compilation)). But in any case, you cannot create a new Forth definition using standard means while compiling of another definition (except a local variable or quotation).

---

A typical approach to have local strings is to use dynamic memory allocation and local variables.

A small library:

```
: str@ ( addr.str -- addr.data u.len )
  dup cell+ swap @
;
: str! ( addr.data u.len  addr.str -- ) >r
  dup r@ cell- @ u> abort" string buffer overflow"
  dup r@ ! \ store the length
  r> cell+ swap ( addr.data addr.buffer u.len )
  2dup + 0 swap c! \ place zero at the end to make ASCIIZ
  move \ store data
;
: new-str ( u.size -- addr.str )
  dup 2 cells + char+ allocate throw tuck ! cell+ ( addr.str )
  dup 0 0 rot str!
;
: free-str ( addr.str -- )
  cell- free throw
;
```

A usage example:

```
: HelloWorld ( -- )
  {: | hw :}
  64 new-str to hw
  s" HelloWorld!" hw str!
  hw str@ cr type cr
  hw free-str
;
```